# CDN / and or Hosting js and css files on a server

Tags: javascript, jquery, reference, cdn

so id like to link a refernce to a couple js files if possible, but im not sure i could go about doing this so i can use it

```
   <script type=text/javascript src=http://mylinkedjs></script>
```

and call i from my jquery.

Anyone know how this is possible?

Comment: Could you clarify the question? It doesn’t make sense at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, what's your question? Do you want to load some js files from a CDN and some from the local server? I really can't follow the quesiton...

Comment: Is there a place where the jquery files can be hosted? and I can reference the link?

Comment: I have the js file hosted here                                 http://www.easy-share.com/1914177377/date.js               when I try and link it in the script tag i get an error

Comment: When I visit that URL in the browser, it doesn’t return a JavaScript file. It returns a web page asking me to buy a premium account for faster downloads. I thus don’t think EasyShare is designed to be used as a CDN for website files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to rephrase your question.

> I want to include some JavaScript files from another server on my page, and call functions from those files in my own jQuery code. Is this possible?

That’s certainly possible. Once you’ve included a JavaScript file on your web page (like you did in the question), the global variables it creates are accessible to any other JavaScript running on that page, regardless of which server the JavaScript file was loaded from.

This is often how jQuery itself is included on pages: by linking to a copy of jQuery on a big CDN, e.g.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

See http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery

Answer (score 2):

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://wherever.com/linked.js">`